# Downloading floor plans

Tags: social-tables

I want to automate the download of the floor plans for my upcoming events. After looking around in the API I couldn't find a method to do this. I can use either the image or the PDF, but I think the PDF is preferred by my users.

If I can't get this using the API is there a URL that I could invoke on the web client that would get me the PDF?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no api for this, and we don't currently have plans to implement this feature.